# How to encode characters in python's splinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8, splinter

I use `splinter` to do functional tests for a website. The tests run well as long as I don't enter special characters, just as German Umlaute.

How can I tweak the script to test entries with these characters as well?

This is what I tried so far:

```
# coding=utf-8

from splinter import Browser


URL = "http://www.example.com"
USER = raw_input("Username, please: ") # f.e. "Günther"

with Browser('') as browser:
    # Log in as administrator
    browser.visit(URL)
browser.fill('user', USER)
```

This is the error log I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 47, in <module>
    browser.fill('user', USER)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\splinter\driver\webdriver\__init__.py", line 230, in fill
    field.value = value
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\splinter\driver\webdriver\__init__.py", line 338, in _set_value
    self._element.send_keys(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 293, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 370, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 164, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 344, in execute
    data = utils.dump_json(params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\utils.py", line 30, in dump_json
    return json.dumps(json_struct)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `USER` as a unicode object:

```
USER = u"Günther"
       ^
```

If the string is come from external source, decode it:

```
USER = USER.decode('<ENCODING-OF-THE-STRING>')
```

Comment: Good hint, but actually I oversimplified the example a bit. I use a `raw_input()` to fetch the variable for `USER`. I updated the example and tried to use `unicode(raw_input())` but that was not the solution. I would be very thankful if you could update your answer...

Comment: @MartinBetz, Try `USER = raw_input("Username, please: ").decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Hm, thanks, this seems right, but I get another error message: `    USER = raw_input("Username, please: ").decode('utf-8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1: invalid start byte`

Comment: It seems like your terminal encoding is not utf-8. In python interactive shell, what does the following statement print? `import sys; print sys.stdin.encoding`. Replace `utf-8` with the printed encoding: `USER = raw_input("Username, please: ").decode('ENCODING_PRINTED')`

Answer (score 0):

[Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) is the most hastle-free unicode handler I've come across.